# matlab matrix error when computing norm

Tags: matlab

Now I have $A =$ $$\begin{bmatrix}0.2 & 0.4\\ 0.21&0.39 \end{bmatrix}$$, and $b=$ $$\begin{bmatrix}0.6\\0.6\\ \end{bmatrix}$$ $\\$

When I solve $Ax=b$, I have the answer $x =$ $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\ \end{bmatrix}$$.

But when I type in `norm(A\[.6;.6] - [1;1])`, I got an error of  $\, 1.9 × 10^{−15}$.
And when I solve $A^{5}x=b^{5}$, I type `norm(A^5\[.6^5;.6^5] - [1;1])`, I got a greater error $1.4 × 10^{−7} $

Why does this happen? Is this related to the machine-$\epsilon$?

Comment: What is $b^5$ supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

$$
A x = b \iff x = A^{-1} b
$$
is equivalent (same solution $x$) iff $A$ is invertible and
$$
A^5 x = A^4 b \iff x = (A^5)^{-1} A^4 b = (A^{-1})^5 A^4 b = A^{-1} b
$$
I assume $A^4 b \ne b^5$ in general, so that must be a different $x$ you are solving for.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ill-conditioned problem. Small errors in storing any values will create very different answers. In this case partly linked to the very small determinant of A.